# Detect locale and set it on angular 2 root module using provider

Tags: angular, locale, angular2-services, angular2-providers

I have a function to detect current locale and I need to set the locale at angular 2 rooot App module via provider. so that i can use that in all other components.

I know i can able to do this like below.

> { provide: 'Locale', useValue: 'en-US' }

But i want to do something like this below if possible.

> { provide: 'Locale', useValue: this.detectLocale() }

Otherwise Please suggest any suitable way to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an `AppConfig` provider that will store configuration and other constant values may be useful in your app.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"

@Injectable()
export class AppConfig()
{
   public endPointUrl: string; // sample configuration value
   public local: string;

   constructor(){
       this.endpointUrl = "";
       this.local = ""; // use detect local logic here
   }
}
```

and provide a singleton instanse of your configuration class:

```
{provide: AppConfig, useValue: new AppConfig()}
```

In this way you can put all your settings and configurations in one place.

Also as I now you can't use `string`s as provider token. Provider tokens only can be class types.